# Cassandra: Refer a table with multiple names

Tags: cassandra

Can we refer a Cassandra table with multiple names ?

Say I have created a table with keyspacename.maintable

Now I want to refer keyspacename.maintable table as

 keyspacename.alternatename1,

 keyspacename.alternatename2,

 keyspacename.alternatename3.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Are you asking if you can create table aliases? Same data but different name?

Comment: @PatrickMcFadin Yes something similar to alias where records from a table can be accessed vai different name.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the need for this. What is the use case that requires a table alias?

Answer (score 0):

Hope Cassandra doesn't have this feature of alais, but this could be achieved using Cassandra datastax driver, cqlengine object mapper. Using object mapper, you can access a table as object with different object names.

Comment: .Object Mapper wont solve my problem. I want to map the table with alternate name. Eg: If I have a table with name keyspacename.maintable and alternate name as keyspacename.newname. Executing a query( select * from maintable or newname ) should provide same result.